# Display multiple google map list

Tags: google-maps, symfony, loops

I am trying to display a list of agency with information such as phone, email etc...and for each a small google map with address. The address is dynamics and render through a loop in twig.

The problem is only the first map is render.

```
function initMap() {
```

var x = document.querySelectorAll('div[id^="map-"]');

```
for(var i  = 1; i < x.length; ++i )
{
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(53.3496, -6.3263);
    var mapOptions = 
    {
        zoom: 16,
        center: latlng
    }

    var stringAddress = '';
    var stringAddress = $("#address-"+i).text();

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-'+ i), mapOptions);

    codeAddress(stringAddress);//call the function
}
```

}

and my code function :

```
function codeAddress(address) {

geocoder.geocode( {address:address}, function(results, status) 
{
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);//center the map over the result
        //place a marker at the location
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker(
        {
            map: map,
            position: results[0].geometry.location
        });
    } else {
        alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
    }
});
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the solution the loop was wrong.

instead of

```
for(var i  = 1; i < x.length; ++i )
```

do

```
for(var i  = 1; i <= x.length; ++i )
```